# Set intersection on results of sqlalchemy queries

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to return the overlap of the results of two ORM queries that would both return a list of integers. I have two tables and I know how to perform the simple filtered queries on them.

```
query1 = session.query(T1.UID).filter(T1.date < now)
query2 = session.query(T2.UID).filter(T2.date < now)
```

What I'd like is a query that will return the UIDs that appear in both of the results that would be returned by these queries.  The individual queries would return a large amount of data but I'm looking for the relatively small overlap.  Conceptually something like `<result of query1>.in_(<result of query2>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple inner join would do it:

```
q = (session.query(T1.UID)
     .join(T2, T1.UID == T2.UID)
     .filter(T1.date < now)
     .filter(T2.date < now)
     )
```

If you really want to use your two queries, below would be the way:

```
query1 = query1.filter(T1.UID.in_(query2.subquery()))
```

Also make sure you have an index on both columns.